# Banking Transaction in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named BankTransaction:

```
Create table BankTransaction 
(
TransactionID int IDENTITY(1,1),
AccountNumber varchar(25) Not Null,
TransactionDate datetime not null Default getdate(), 
TransactionType varchar(25) Not Null,
TransactionAmount money Default '0',
BalanceAsOf money Default '0' ,
Primary Key(TransactionID) 
);


Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('123AABDF','Credit','22535.215');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('123AABDF','Debit','215.9');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2256DF','Credit','500');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2256DF','Debit','100');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2351AV','Credit','5000');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2351AV','Debit','100');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('123AABDF','Debit','235.215');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2256DF','Credit','1000');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2351AV','Credit','500');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('7865HNH','Credit','982000');
```

what I want is that The account having same AccountNumber if the TransactionType is Debit then subtract from BalanceAsOf and if the TransactionType is Credit then adding to BalanceAsOF:

This is what I tried but doesn't work:

```
update bt
                        Set  BalanceAsOF = case 

                        when AccountNumber=AccountNumber and  TransactionType = 'Credit' 
                        then ( BalanceAsOf + TransactionAmount )
                        when  AccountNumber=AccountNumber AND TransactionType='Debit' 
                        then BalanceAsOf - TransactionAmount
                        End 
                        from
                        dbo.BankTransaction as bt

                        Select * From dbo.BankTransaction as p
```

Comment: It's usually best *not* to store computable data, unless and until there's a proven performance issue. All you immediately do by storing such data is to *introduce the possibility of it being wrong/out of sync*.

Comment: or you can store the value of BalanceAsOf while populating itself.Above allfrom your query we are not able to make out what is the correct value of BalanceAsOf.so better explain the desire output.

Comment: let's assume a person deposits rs. 100 the the BalanceAsOf should show Rs.100 and if the same person withdraws rs.60 then the BalanceAsOf should show rs.40 And if there is entirely different person depositing Rs.500 then the BalanceAsOf should show Rs.500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you should do

```
set nocount on;

Create table BankTransaction 
(
TransactionID int IDENTITY(1,1),
AccountNumber varchar(25) Not Null,
TransactionDate datetime not null Default getdate(), 
TransactionType varchar(25) Not Null,
TransactionAmount money Default '0',
BalanceAsOf money Default '0' ,
Primary Key(TransactionID) 
);


Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('123AABDF','Credit','22535.215');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('123AABDF','Debit','215.9');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2256DF','Credit','500');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2256DF','Debit','100');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2351AV','Credit','5000');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2351AV','Debit','100');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('123AABDF','Debit','235.215');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2256DF','Credit','1000');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('2351AV','Credit','500');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('7865HNH','Credit','982000');

Insert into dbo.BankTransaction(AccountNumber,TransactionType,TransactionAmount) 
Values ('876YYT','Credit','27363647');


  Create Table #AccountNomber (
  AccountNumber varchar(25) Not Null,);

insert into #AccountNomber ( AccountNumber)
Select  Distinct BT.AccountNumber 
  From dbo.BankTransaction as BT 

  --select * from #AccountNomber


   Declare @PreviousBalance money
   Set @PreviousBalance = 0 

   declare @AcctNumber varchar(25)
   declare @TransactionId int

     --update b 
     --set b.BalanceAsOf=0
     --from BankTransaction b

   while exists(select 1 from #AccountNomber)
   begin
     select @AcctNumber = a.AccountNumber from #AccountNomber a

     --select 'test',* from BankTransaction b
     --where b.AccountNumber=@AcctNumber
     --and b.BalanceAsOf=0
     --order by b.TransactionID
     --/*
     while exists (select 1 from BankTransaction b where b.AccountNumber=@AcctNumber
     and b.BalanceAsOf=0
     )
     begin
     select @TransactionId = (select top 1 b.TransactionID from BankTransaction b
     where b.AccountNumber=@AcctNumber
     and b.BalanceAsOf=0
     order by b.TransactionID)

     select @PreviousBalance =@PreviousBalance + case when b.TransactionType='Credit' then b.TransactionAmount else -1*b.TransactionAmount end
     from BankTransaction b
     Where b.AccountNumber=@AcctNumber
     and b.TransactionID=@TransactionId

     update b 
     set b.BalanceAsOf=@PreviousBalance
     from BankTransaction b
     Where b.AccountNumber=@AcctNumber
     and b.TransactionID=@TransactionId

     end
    select @PreviousBalance =0
    delete a from #AccountNomber a
    where a.AccountNumber=@AcctNumber

   End





   select * from BankTransaction b
   order by b.TransactionID

   Drop table BankTransaction 
   drop table #AccountNomber
```

Comment: Thank you @Nirajan That was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to store the current Balance for each transaction? If you just want to display the balance to user you can have a column in Accounts table for example and for every transaction (`insert into BankTransaction`) you update this column via trigger on `BankTransaction` or through your application.

**UPDATE**
Use a trigger to calculate the balance before inserting the new transaction

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_UpdBalance
ON [BankTransaction]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BankTransaction
        AccountNumber, 
        TransactionType, 
        TransactionAmount, 
        BalanceAsOf
    SELECT 
        i.AccountNumber, 
        i.TransactionType, 
        i.TransactionAmount, 
        CASE 
            WHEN i.TransactionType = 'Credit' 
                THEN ( bt.BalanceAsOf + i.TransactionAmount )
            WHEN i.TransactionType='Debit' 
                THEN bt.BalanceAsOf - i.TransactionAmount
        END 
      FROM   Inserted i
     INNER JOIN BankTransaction bt 
      ON BT.AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber 
        AND TransactionID = (SELECT MAX(TransactionID) 
                            FROM BankTransaction 
                            WHERE AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber)

  END
```

Comment: Yes, because i want to know a person's Balance at the exact time the transaction is happening

Comment: @MelinaSharma is that what you want?

Comment: Kostis I got an error with your code but the comment by @Nirajan Pokharel was what i was looking for